# `gulp build` for semantic ui is giving error 'ENOENT: no such file or directory'

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, semantic-ui

version:

> gulp@3.9.1

I have installed `semantic-ui`  through `npm install` and given default settings during interactive  setup process.

But when i do `gulp build` from the `/semantic` folder i am getting following error:

```
[20:52:27] Starting 'build'...
Building Semantic
[20:52:27] Starting 'build-javascript'...
Building Javascript
[20:52:27] Starting 'build-css'...
Building CSS
[20:52:27] Starting 'build-assets'...
Building assets
[20:52:28] Created: dist/components/site.js
[20:52:28] Created: dist/components/site.min.js
[20:52:28] Created: dist/components/form.js
[20:52:28] Created: dist/components/form.min.js
[20:52:28] Created: dist/components/accordion.js
[20:52:28] Created: dist/components/accordion.min.js
[20:52:28] Created: dist/components/checkbox.js
[20:52:28] Created: dist/components/dimmer.js
[20:52:28] Created: dist/components/checkbox.min.js
[20:52:28] Created: dist/components/dimmer.min.js
[20:52:28] Created: dist/components/dropdown.js
[20:52:29] Created: dist/components/embed.js
[20:52:29] Created: dist/components/dropdown.min.js
[20:52:29] Created: dist/components/reset.css
[20:52:29] Created: dist/components/reset.min.css
[20:52:29] Created: dist/components/modal.js
[20:52:29] Created: dist/components/embed.min.js
[20:52:29] Created: dist/components/modal.min.js
```

Later this error throws up

```
[20:52:31] Starting 'package uncompressed js'...
[20:52:31] Finished 'build-javascript' after 4.23 s
[20:52:31] Created: dist/components/container.min.css
[20:52:31] Created: dist/components/container.css
fs.js:839
  return binding.lstat(pathModule._makeLong(path));
                 ^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat '/Users/venkat299/code/harvest_api/harvest_server/semantic/dist/components/semantic.min.js'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an issue with `gulp-header 1.8.3` causing this.

https://github.com/tracker1/gulp-header/issues/37

Add `"gulp-header": "1.8.2"` directly to your `package.json` and you should be fine.

Remove the `^` from the version number if it's already there, it pushes you up to the next `minor` version, which will cause the problem.

Answer (score 5):

The solution that worked for me (by DaniVarga [here](https://github.com/tracker1/gulp-header/issues/37)) was this:

```
npm uninstall gulp-header
npm install gulp-header@1.8.2 --save
```

... then ...

```
gulp build
```

Comment: Helped me as well!

Comment: I don't know what a package.json is. This saved me.

Answer (score 2):

Does adding `"gulp-header": "1.8.2",` to your package.json help?

See https://github.com/miickel/gulp-angular-templatecache/issues/124.