# Semantic-UI Build Error on Heroku

Tags: heroku, semantic-ui

I have a Node app where I used to deploy it to Heroku. It works perfectly on my local environment (using OSX). When I try to deploy another build to heroku yesterday, I started to get an error while semantic-ui is built.

```
remote:        fs.js:839
remote:        return binding.lstat(pathModule._makeLong(path));
remote:        ^
remote:        
remote:        Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat '/tmp/build_f3f2aa87a64a76efc1453a48016c1026/semantic/dist/components/semantic.js'
```

Has anyone experienced this kind of an issue? I have no idea how to solve it. Thanks

[image: Error showing on terminal]

Comment: Refer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/37886836/2797942

Comment: Yeah I found that as well. Thank you @Jhn. It solved the problem